# Adding a value to an array element that is a reference of another object

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, reference

Excuse me, this question maybe exist in a different form but I really searched everywhere and don't see it.

I have worked in C++ and am used to pointers. I am having problem with substituting my logic with C# analogue code.

Here is my C# code

```
abstract class Parent
{

    protected virtual int foo();
}

public class Son : Parent
{
    public Parent A { get; set; }
    public Parent B { get; set; }

    protected override int foo()
    {
         return base.foo();
    }

}

public class Daughter : Parent
{
    public Parent A { get; set; }
    public Parent B { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Son P1 = new Son();
    Parent X = new Daughter();
    Parent[] array = new Parent[10];
    array[0] = P1;
    array[1] = P1.A;
    array[2] = P1.B;   

    array[1]= X;

    //I expect P1.A to be X but it is null
}
```

I want array to be some kind of a holder for future instances that will be added directly to objects fields.

Comment: Please avoid duplicating your own question. You've already asked this question earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566922/adding-an-instance-to-reference-that-is-field-in-another-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You never assign a value to P1.A, so it is still null.
You actually assign value to array[1] two times: first time you assign P1.A, second time to X. no relationship bewtwen the two referenced values.

You can thing that a C# reference (such array[1] or object obj = new Object()) is similar to a c++ pointer.

In your example, replace . with a ->, and try to think how it would work in c++: it works the same in c#

[Edit]

In c++ you would write:

```
Son* P1 = new Son();
Parent* X = new Parent();

Parent* array[10]; // an array of 10 pointers
//TODO: zeromemory all elements of array, c++ does't iniziatialize pointers
array[1] = P1->A;
array[1] = X;
```

in c#, you write the above code like this:

```
Son P1 = new Son();
Parent X = new Parent();

Parent array[10]; // an array of 10 reference to Parent, c# initialize all references to null
array[1] = P1.A;
array[1] = X;
```